# Cassandra: Data skewness

Tags: cassandra

We have a 10-node Cassandra cluster. The data size looks very skewed on a few nodes. The cluster is setup using vnodes (32).

I am looking for suggestions on how to figure out why is there data skewness and how to balance the cluster.

Nodetool status output

```
Datacenter: us-west-2_central
=============================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.20.111.20  832.35 GB  32      ?       a3e94d59-5897-46a5-afe7-b695b0179461  2b
UN  172.20.111.16  895.15 GB  32      ?       7e2f7726-3b98-4535-b44d-c522f7a0d4e6  2b
UN  172.20.110.17  1.39 TB    32      ?       925dc818-04d2-4dfa-a54b-6e0b4098fd76  2a
UN  172.20.111.18  861.17 GB  32      ?       acc23bfe-33ee-41b6-b78e-1d813697c9b1  2b
UN  172.20.110.19  835.67 GB  32      ?       5e2fd25a-5bbd-42c2-a627-a134c0e20c8b  2a
UN  172.20.110.13  932.74 GB  32      ?       d7534422-de99-49cb-a026-f3fa5ff8c16b  2a
UN  172.20.111.14  782.67 GB  32      ?       80802902-fd4a-4271-8dd9-d7421d823bd2  2b
UN  172.20.110.15  1.03 TB    32      ?       82535a06-30ee-4e7a-9e1e-ca6d33648ce8  2a
UN  172.20.110.10  697.58 GB  32      ?       bcf265b1-6e82-4d12-9e7c-2b769ccf1d3a  2a
UN  172.20.111.11  786.71 GB  32      ?       d34bcb42-f061-49d9-b4b1-41ae140d868b  2b
```

You can see there is a node with 1.39 TB  and other node with 1.03 TB.

Comment: Is the replication factor (RF) the same for all keyspaces?

Comment: Have you run nodetool cleanup on all nodes after scaling?

Comment: Also you might have some old snapshots or backups.

Comment: @TomerSan Mostly RF is 2. For just 1 very small keyspace, RF is 3.

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson Yes. nodetool cleanup is run on all nodes sequentially.

Comment: @Mandraenke I checked; there are no snapshots or backups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be different causes for this problem. For example your data model may be the reason for skewness. If you have a table that has small number of very wide partitions (millions of rows per partition) it may be the cause of this problem. These kind of partitions may end up in particular replicas, which may cause skewness.

Also, this skewness may be totally by chance. I mean, the token allocation between nodes may end up with this skewness all by chance. If this is the scenario, and if the problem gets bigger over time, you may need to replace the highly-loaded nodes with new ones.

Take a look at this article: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/token-allocation-algorithm

Comment: I tend to agree with you. I think data skewness is by chance. I checked "nodetool cfstats" on couple of high and low loaded nodes. The partition max size is  400/500 MB in high ones and the low ones have 100+ MB max partition size. Will it distribute the token ranges if I add new nodes and expand the cluster and remove the highly loaded ones? I am using Cassandra 2.1.x.

Comment: Are there any tools available to print statistics of the partitions contained in a node for a particular table and using which we can infer details about data skewness?

Comment: You can use nodetool tablestats to get more information about a particular table. Also, you can use graphana/graphite to display Cassandra metrics in a user friendly way. Check this out: https://blog.pythian.com/monitoring-apache-cassandra-metrics-graphite-grafana/

Comment: Your partition sizes are relatively large. So this may be the problem of skewness. You might consider different table models (more granular partitions) if this is possible. Also, you can increase vnode numbers per node. Removing the heavy-load node and adding a new one might also help.  You should make your cluster re-share the ring while you are doing this because simply replacing a node with a new one by using replace_address will make the new-node take the same load again.

Comment: Yes. I am planning to add two more nodes to the cluster. And once cluster is up with 12 nodes, I will remove the two high loaded ones. Will share result.